# How to change image size on category page when click swatch

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, magento1.9.2.4

On Category page I have configurable product. 
I set image resize on 
`/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

But  when i click swatch color images show size nomal

Help me, please

[image]

Comment: provide site url for better understanding.i'm not sure if your image size reduce or div height?

Comment: i check image size reduce  because code resize but i don't know code on file

Comment: I'm new with magento and facing same issue and I'm still digging into. I've set the "small image width" in catalog section but still it's getting smaller when i click on color swatch box.
Could anyone please help fixing this would be highly appreciated.